# Linux slow command response despite no apparent load

Tags: linux, centos

Once in a while some of my Linux boxes enter some kind of strange state that results in having to reboot them.

All commands take about 5 seconds to execute. But if you run the same command twice in a row, the first will take 5 seconds, but the second will be instant. Even the time command doesn't see the 5 seconds:

```
[root@node48 ~]# time echo 1
1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
[root@node48 ~]# time echo 1
1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
[root@node48 ~]# time echo 2
2

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
[root@node48 ~]# time echo 2
2

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

In the above example, the 1st echo took 5 seconds, the 2nd was instant, the 3rd took 5 seconds, the 4th was instant. Yet all 'time' results are 0.

I'm confused as to what might cause this. Load was non-existent on this node, and the problem persisted even after I stopped all running services on it.

```
[root@node48 ~]# top
top - 16:17:22 up 42 days, 11:02,  1 user,  load average: 0.17, 0.83, 1.20
Tasks: 292 total,   1 running, 291 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.4%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32934476k total, 21642992k used, 11291484k free,    11296k buffers
Swap:  4095996k total,        0k used,  4095996k free,   343152k cached
```

There's no swap usage, no zombies, plenty of cpu idle time.

What would you look at if you would have such an issue?

Thank you,

Comment: does it happen with all commands? how about memory usage and io activity? Do you see any difference before and after dropping cache (`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`)?

Comment: 1.check `ps -ef` for strange process     
2.disk io activity

Comment: Potentially your connection to the (over ssh) is very slow or has some issue (eg failing interface). Also, are you doing this in a VM ? If so, are other guests on the same VM competing for resources? Check also dmesg. Does the problem go away if cron is stopped? Are there heavy jobs running (assuming this may be a compute node)

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL Yes, this happens on all commands. I showed example with echo as it's a very simple command that should execute right away. I will try drop cache that next time.

Comment: @Corleone No io activity, all services stopped

Comment: @CameronKerr It's a physical node. SSH connection is good, local network. no packet loss. Problem still happens after stopping all services. Will check dmesg next time

Comment: Use strace to see what takes so long.

Comment: Something bad/unavailable in your PATH? What if you use time /bin/echo instead? (Assuming that echo is not a shell built-in). I would second the suggestion to also try strace, with timing info. Do you have things like sssd (network auth) or nfs/samba in play also? Does this problem ever occur when there is disk IO happening?

Answer (score 1):

tldr; `systemctl | grep "abandoned" | cut -f3 -d ' ' | xargs systemtctl stop` fixed it for me.

I noticed for me, not all commands were slow, specifically things having to do with logins were slow (ssh, w, top, etc) but other things like `iostat`, `ls`, etc were speedy.

When doing an `strace -v w` for instance, I noticed it got hung up waiting on D-bus. Of course D-bus is tied intrinsically to systemd, you can not just restart D-bus without rebooting. So I did some poking and searching and noticed:

`systemctl | grep "abandoned" | wc -l` returned 711 for this machine. (you can also see this information `ls -l /run/systemd/sessions/ | wc -l`).

That's a lot of abandoned login sessions that never got cleaned up.  I cleaned them up: `systemctl | grep "abandoned" | cut -f3 -d ' ' | xargs systemctl stop` and everything got instantly better.

I'm not saying this will fix your machine, but it fixed mine, and it might help the poor lost souls who end up here like me without a great place to start.